# Error running pod install: Exit code 1 from: pod install

Tags: plugins, flutter

I am building a touchid plugin for my flutter app.  I found that some of the features are only available in ios9 or >.  I changed my plugin.podspec to s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0' from s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'

The app builds with errors related to the ios 9 requirement, but gets the 
Error running pod install: Exit code 1 from: pod install when I change the podspec file and will not build or run.

Any ideas?  I ran pod repo update and made no difference.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try `flutter run -v` and post your logs?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably see an error like this if you run with `flutter run -v`.

> Unable to satisfy the following requirements...
>
> Specs satisfying the
>   `plugin_name` (from
>   `/Users/jackson/git/plugins/packages/plugin_name/ios`) dependency
>   were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

The solution is to uncomment the line at the top of your example project's `Podfile`.

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
```

There's not currently a way for your plugin to force this to happen. You can [file an issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new) if this bothers you.